# Research topics involving statistics and basic topology or discrete math

Tags: general-topology, statistics, discrete-mathematics, research

I'm starting to get involve into statistic and probability topics, and would like to know if you could recommmend me a research topic about both statistics and another field such as basic topology, discrete math or another math field that doesn't require a full and deep math knowledge. Sorry if the question is too open, what I need is basically some research topics just to get a starting point in statistics research. Thank you in advance

Comment: Perhaps you should find a lab you are interested in at your university (if you are an undergrad) and ask the professor if you can do research with them.

Comment: @LazyLee I asked a couple of seniors how to do that but there are only physics and chemistry labs available (CS and math are not that active because burocratic reasons :/)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking out the site Open Problem Garden (Link: http://www.openproblemgarden.org/). They have a collection of unsolved problems in mathematics. Even if none of the particular problems interest you, I'm sure you will be able to find an area that interests you.

Comment: Is a really interesting website, but I'm not looking for "unsolved particular problems" but investigation areas or research fields involving statistics subjects